# Implementing mail templates using Struts 2 taglib in custom JSP template

Tags: java, email, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I'm building an app that leverages Struts 2 as the primary framework, but one of the requirements is that the app sends automated emails.

Since Struts 2 doesn't include much helpfulness out-of-the-box in terms of implementing mail templates, I decided to just use normal JSP, like this:

```
public static String parseJSPTemplate(String jspPath, HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher jsp = req.getRequestDispatcher(jspPath);
    EmailTemplateHandler tpl = new EmailTemplateHandler();
    jsp.forward(req, tpl);
    return tpl.toString();
}
```

So, this processes the JSP in a normal way and returns a string representation of the output with variables replaced, etc.

One would *think* that including the Struts 2 taglib per usual (e.g. `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`) would allow the use of tags like `<s:url />`; however, it seems that this is not the case. Instead, the result of the call to the `taglib` is blank. No errors are displayed, nor exceptions thrown.

My guess is that something else needs to be injected into the request before Struts 2 will properly respond to calls, but I'm not sure what this would be.

Anyone have an idea on how to get this working? Other `taglib`s like JSTL-core work fine.

Comment: How did you call a taglib to produce result and what is your expectations?

Comment: I loaded the taglib as described above and called it like this: `<s: url action="index" namespace="/my/namespace" />`. My expectation is that it would return a URL to that action including the context root. Instead, it produces nothing (blank).

Comment: *Yuck*. Personally I'd use only something like FreeMarker/etc for email templating. JSP is verbose and a PITA to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Struts tags are working if the `ActionContext` is available. Normally it's created by the `Dispatcher` in prepare operations. So, the struts2 filter should be mapped to accept  `DispatcherType.FORWARD` requests to be invoked on your forward. You can also get the action context via `ActionContext.getContext()` in the JSP for debugging.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how one might go about ensuring the ActionContext is available and/or how to ensure it's included during DispatcherType.FORWARD operations?

Comment: If the context is `null` then it's not available. To ensure it you should map a filter on such operations. Add `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` to your filter mapping. Debug JSP to to ensure action context is available.